# error when decorating angular $http

Tags: angularjs, http, decorator, angular-decorator

I'm trying to implement a simple decorator of $http.get().  After calling get(), I want to pass the return promise to my own service, ProgressBar.  (My service works fine in the controller, FWIW.)

```js
$provide.decorator('$http',function($delegate,ProgressBar){
  //GET
  var tempGet=$delegate.get;
  $delegate.get=function(){
    var args    = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)
    var httpPromise=tempGet.apply(undefined,args);//(arguments[0],arguments[1]);
    ProgressBar.inProgressAsync(httpPromise);
  };
  return $delegate;
});
```

However, I get following error.

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$http.get(tpl, httpOptions)
        ['finally']')
handleRequestFn@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17554:41
ngIncludeWatchAction@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:24143:29
constantListener@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14276:25
$digest@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15715:31
$apply@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15986:31
bootstrapApply@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1658:21
invoke@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4473:22
doBootstrap@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1656:20
bootstrap@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1676:23
angularInit@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1570:14
http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:28683:16
fire@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3148:35
fireWith@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3260:11
ready@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3472:24
completed@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3503:15
```

I think (?) I'm malforming the http request but I can't see how.  Any thoughts.  Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you're overriding the `$http.get` but you're returning nothing. Try return `httpPromise` in your `$delegate.get` method.

Comment: Ugh.  I must be getting tired.  Adding 'return httpPromise;' fixed the error.  Thank you.  If you want the answer points, turn you comment into an answer and I'll accept.